# Why does method channelActive always be called in server and client - Netty

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I'm using the following working example. This might be a "wall of code", but the question is simple: Why does the method `channelActive` always be called? If you don't want to read the code, you can find the example here too. [Netty Server Client Pojo example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=TFdream%2Fnetty-tutorials%2Fnetty-tutorials-master%2Fnetty-pojo-demo%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fmindflow%2Fnetty4%2Fpojo%2FPojoServer.java#)

NettyClient:

```
public class NettyClient {

    private String host;
    private int port = 5000;

    public NettyClient(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public void send() throws InterruptedException {

        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

                    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                    p.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());
                    p.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
                    p.addLast(new NettyClientHandler());
                }
            });

            ChannelFuture future = b.connect(host, port).sync();

            future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

}
```

NettyClientHandler

```
public class NettyClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private DeviceMessage deviceMessage;

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // Send the message to JLoggerServer - contains deviceName, slider0, slider1, slider2, slider3, slider4, slider5 
        System.out.println("Channel active - client");
        ctx.write(deviceMessage);

    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        // Read the response from JLoggerServer - Contains deviceName, adc0, adc1, adc2, adc3, adc4, adc5
        DeviceMessage responseMessage = (DeviceMessage) msg;
        deviceMessage.setAdcValues(responseMessage.getAdcValues());
        System.out.println("read from server");
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

NettyServer

```
public class NettyServer extends Thread{

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private int port = 5000;

    public NettyServer() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024)
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

                    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                    p.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());
                    p.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
                    p.addLast(new NettyServerHandler());
                }
            });

            // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync(); // (7)

            logger.info("server bind port:{}", port);

            // Wait until the server socket is closed.
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

}
```

And at the end, NettyServerHandler.

```
public class NettyServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, SerialPort> allDevices;

    /**
     * This will be called when we send something from client to server and server
     * will respond
     */
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Read from client");

        // Get message
        DeviceMessage deviceMessage = (DeviceMessage) msg;
        System.out.println(deviceMessage.getDevicename());
        SerialPort serialPort = allDevices.get(deviceMessage.getDevicename());
        if (serialPort == null)
            return;

        // Create TXData memory with twice of length as values array and insert its values
        byte[] TXData = new byte[deviceMessage.getSliderValues().length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < TXData.length; i += 2) {
            TXData[i] = (byte) (deviceMessage.getSliderValues()[i] & 0xff);
            TXData[i + 1] = (byte) ((deviceMessage.getSliderValues()[i] >> 8) & 0xff);

            System.out.println("Slider" + i + ": " + deviceMessage.getSliderValues()[i]);
        }

        // Write to JLoggerDevice
        serialPort.writeBytes(TXData, TXData.length);

        // Create RXData memory with twice of length as values array and read the ADC values from JLoggerDevice
        byte[] RXData = new byte[deviceMessage.getAdcValues().length * 2];
        int receivedBytes = serialPort.bytesAvailable();
        while (receivedBytes < RXData.length)
            receivedBytes = serialPort.bytesAvailable(); // We need to have values.length * 2 bytes to pass
        serialPort.readBytes(RXData, RXData.length);

        // Create them to short
        for (int i = 0; i < RXData.length / 2; i++) {
            deviceMessage.getAdcValues()[i] = (short) ((RXData[i + 1] << 8) + (RXData[i] & 0xFF));
            System.out.println("Adc" + i + ": " + deviceMessage.getAdcValues()[i]);
        }

        // Write back message to the client
        ctx.write(deviceMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Channel active - server");
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        logger.error("server caught exception", cause);
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I start the NettyServer.

```
        // Start the Netty server
        try {
            new NettyServer().start();
            logger.info("Starting netty server");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
        }
```

I get always this as putput when I try to write from Client -> Server.

Client side:

```
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
Channel active - client
```

And server side:

```
2019-09-25 20:43:34.688  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-2] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:34.984  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:35.268  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-4] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:35.571  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-1] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:35.855  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-2] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:36.137  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:36.468  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-4] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:36.777  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-1] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:37.072  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-2] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:37.364  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:37.648  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-4] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:37.930  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-1] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:38.214  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-2] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:38.503  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler           : Channel active - server
2019-09-25 20:43:38.797  INFO 8639 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-4] s.d.J.netty.NettyServerHandler
```

We can at least say that the client is connected to the server. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`channelActive` is called each time a new connection is accepted. I suspect you create a new connection when writing from the client to the server.

Comment: Yes. But so what should I do when a connection appear? I try to write, but nothing happens.

Comment: you need to call `writeAndFlush(...)`

Comment: And yes. When I call `send()`, then a channel goes active for the client and then for the server a channel goes active. Then the client channels shut down gradefully.

Comment: what is the status of the returned ChannelFuture ? Did you inspect if it failed ?

Comment: Now I have stop using Netty and I'm using a REST API HTTP instead. I found Netty difficult to use. Sorry. But to answer you question, I did not get any returned status. It seems as when I open a channel from client and send directly, then the server open a channel to. But the message don't receive to the server. If you want to see my solution. Please check out: https://github.com/DanielMartensson/JLogger